# Why is my addEventListener going off over and over again?

Tags: javascript, html

This double for loop is supposed to loop over a Battleship board and add an event listener to each cell. The event listener is supposed to represent a cell in a Battleship board. When it is clicked and a ship is positioned on that cell, the cell's color will change to red, representing a hit, and w will increment by 2. If w reaches 24, the game will end and the winner's scores will be presented.

```
let table2 = document.getElementById("player2board");
        let opptable2 = document.getElementById("player1opp");
        for(var i = 1; i < table2.rows.length; i++){
          for(var j = 1; j < table2.rows[i].cells.length; j++){
            table2.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = p2Board[i - 1][j - 1];
            if(p2Board[i - 1][j - 1] != ""){
              let currcell = opptable2.rows[i].cells[j];
              opptable2.rows[i].cells[j].addEventListener("click", () => {currcell.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
              document.getElementById("player1table").hidden = true;
              w += 2;
              console.log(w);
              if(w == 24){
                let t = w;
                w = w - w2;
                w2 = w2 - t;
                document.getElementById("p1score").innerText = p1Name + "'s score (winner): " + w;
                document.getElementById("p2score").innerText = p2Name + "'s score: " + w2;
                document.getElementById("scores").hidden = false;
              }else{
                document.getElementById("player2turn").hidden = false;
              }});
            }else{
              let currcell = opptable2.rows[i].cells[j];
              opptable2.rows[i].cells[j].addEventListener("click", () => {currcell.style.backgroundColor = "White";
              document.getElementById("player1table").hidden = true; document.getElementById("player2turn").hidden = false;});
            }
          }
        }
```

What's going wrong, though, is that the event listener is incrementing w for every hit that has been made. If I click on a cell and get a 2nd hit, w will increment by 4, if I get a 3rd hit w will increment by 8 etc. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by going off and on? Is the w not incrementing? Have you tried `console.log(w)` inside the event listener to see what is going on?

Comment: @AliMustafa You can see that they have by the code in their example

Comment: I mean that w is being incremented exponentially for every time there has been a hit when I only want it to increment by 2 whenever there is a hit

Comment: So that means you keep adding event listeners to the element. So you are setting addEventListener multiple times. So the answer is: Figure out how are you binding the events more than once. You do not provide that info above so hard for us to know why you are binding events more than once.

Comment: @G-b2001 Please edit your title. Going on and off isn't the problem you are facing. And also try pasting complete code.

Comment: @Ali Mustafa Where does it say that it is going on and off?